# How to exchange values betwwen async function which are running forever in python3.5?

Tags: python-3.x, arguments, python-asyncio

I'm trying to learn python async module, and I have searched everywhere on the Internet including youtube pycon and various other videos, but i could not find a way to get variables from one async function (running forever) and to pass variable to other async function (running forever)

demo code:

```
async def one():
    while True:
        ltp += random.uniform(-1, 1)
        return ltp

async def printer(ltp):
    while True:
        print(ltp)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As with any other Python code, the two coroutines can communicate using an object they both share, most typically `self`:

```
class Demo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ltp = 0

    async def one(self):
        while True:
            self.ltp += random.uniform(-1, 1)
            await asyncio.sleep(0)

    async def two(self):
        while True:
            print(self.ltp)
            await asyncio.sleep(0)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
d = Demo()
loop.create_task(d.one())
loop.create_task(d.two())
loop.run_forever()
```

The issue with the above code is that `one()` keeps producing values regardless of whether anyone is reading them. Also, there is no guarantee that `two()` is not running faster than `one()`, in which case it will see the same value more than once. The solution to both problems is to communicate via a bounded queue:

```
class Demo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = asyncio.Queue(1)

    async def one(self):
        ltp = 0
        while True:
            ltp += random.uniform(-1, 1)
            await self.queue.put(ltp)

    async def two(self):
        while True:
            ltp = await self.queue.get()
            print(ltp)
            await asyncio.sleep(0)
```

Comment: inside a class its local, so they can access the value, but what if they cant access locally?

Comment: @user1779646 Then they should receive some instance as an argument. For example: `loop.create_task(one(some_obj)); loop.create_task(two(some_obj))`. They can then use `some_obj.attribute...` to exchange information.

Comment: if i put 2 in asyncio.Queue(1), will it put 2 different values in queue or same values getting used twice?

Comment: @user1779646 Sorry, I'm not sure I understood your question. By *put 2 in asyncio.Queue(1)*, are you referring to something like `queue.put(2)`, or to changing the queue size from `asyncio.Queue(1)` to `asyncio.Queue(2)`?

Comment: I'm basically asking what does this "item" in:-    coroutine put(item) does, i could not understand from the docs.

Comment: could you pls refer me any good article on sharing data between unshared memory, be it multiprocessing , threading or async. though trheading is shared

Comment: @user1779646 `item` is any value you want to read on the other side. (The other side being the coroutine one that calls `get`.) In our case, the coroutine that produces random numbers is putting the numbers in, and the other one is getting them out.

Comment: can i do (get)  twice  after( put),  to get the same values, or will the values get lost after first .get, ?